# Setting a variable whose value can be used in other console terminal sessions

Tags: environment-variables

I would like to set a variable whose value can be retained when instantiating another terminal session.  What can I use?

Answer (score 0):

You would define it inside your `.bashrc` file located in your home directory, or for every user, `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

This will depend on how you login as well. If it’s a remote login, and you don’t see the variable value, use your `.profile` file.

There’s a section about environment variables and how they load (from what file) during your terminal session in `man bash`.

Comment: I would like that the variable be set by the user that would be retained for other session, unless the user want to reset it or unset it later on.

Answer (score 0):

To set a variable who's value should be available when initiating another terminal session, you will need to include it in `~/.bashrc`. Then, any other terminal session *started **after** that variable has been set* will have it available. This could be implemented by manually editing `~/.bashrc` or by a script that modifies that file. In its simplest form, a command like `echo export MYVAR=value >> ~/.bashrc` already makes the variable available for future interactive shells.

It is not possible to set a variable and automatically have this available in another currently running instance.

This is due to how the system of environmental variables works. You cannot set a variable in one instance of the shell that then becomes available in another instance. This is due to so called "inheritance". A shell inherits the environment of the shell from which it is launched, and then only inherits variables that have been *exported*. Variables that just have been set are not available in that subshell.

Thus, environmental variables exported in your `~/.profile` will be set when you log in and be in effect for any shell you launch or process you start. Environmental variables you set or export in your `~/.bashrc` will be available as soon as you open an interactive bash shell.

Comment: I am good with having any other terminal session started after the variable has been set will have it available.